# GnuRadio's SNR estimators usage

Tags: snr, gnuradio

I'm trying to calculate the SNR of a satellite signal using GRC, but all of the 4 offered estimators either have a lot of *-NaN* values or are ~35dB throughout the entire recording. 
(I just connected the file source to the MPSK SNR estimator probe and redirected the messages to message debug.)

I've tried the [examples](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-digital/examples/snr_estimators.py#L91) adapted to my input and M2M4 estimator spits out somewhat expected values (so I've been told by others in the company).

The code:

```
from sys import argv
from scipy import fromfile, absolute, array_split, mean, sqrt, log10, ceil, linspace, complex64
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def snr_est_m2m4(signal):
    M2 = mean(absolute(signal)**2)
    M4 = mean(absolute(signal)**4)
    snr_rat = sqrt(2*M2*M2 - M4) / (M2 - sqrt(2*M2*M2 - M4))
    return 10.0*log10(snr_rat)

def chunkify(lst, chunk_size):
    return [lst[i * chunk_size : (i+1) * chunk_size] for i in range(int(ceil(len(lst)/chunk_size)))]

def main():
    if len(argv) != 2:
        return
    bits = fromfile(argv[1], dtype=complex64)
    m2m4_axis = [absolute(snr_est_m2m4(s)) for s in array_split(bits, 100000)]

    f1 = plt.figure(1)
    s1 = f1.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    chunk_size = 100
    smooth_m2m4 = [mean(c) for c in chunkify(m2m4_axis, chunk_size)]
    s1.plot(linspace(0, 1000, len(smooth_m2m4)), smooth_m2m4, 'b-', label='m2m4')
    s1.grid(True)
    s1.set_xlabel('time')
    s1.set_ylabel('snr')
    s1.legend()
    print("Done!")
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the output I receive:
[image: python_m2_m4_estimation]

I know the recording is valid since the GRC chain we currently have implemented gives out an image of the Earth. 
I've tried the estimators on a different signal but yet again, the values didn't make sense; the SNR was higher when there was no signal.

What do the parameters `alpha` and `Samples between SNR messages` in GRC represent? Why don't the estimators in GRC work as expected? What is the suggested way of calculating SNR?

I'm at a loss here, please send help.

Comment: Is there a PSK signal in your signal?

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that - it's a QPSK from the Meteor M2 satellite.

Comment: By the way, have you looked at the official [documentation](https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1digital_1_1mpsk__snr__est__m2m4.html) of that block? The alpha is "alpha the update rate of internal running average calculations.", i.e. probably a single-tap IIR ("exponentially weighted moving average") with feeback coefficient alpha.

Comment: Nan's are common for the M2M4 estimator; the system of quadratic equations used to compute it are not guaranteed to have a real non-negative solution. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54099/advances-in-blind-snr-estimation-beyond-m-2m-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [documentation](https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1digital_1_1mpsk__snr__est__m2m4.html) of that block:

> An SNR estimator for M-PSK signals that uses 2nd (M2) and 4th
>   (M4) order moments. This estimator uses knowledge of the
>   kurtosis of the signal ($k_a)$ and noise ($k_w$) to make its
>   estimation. We use Beaulieu's approximations here to M-PSK
>   signals and AWGN channels such that $k_a=1$ and $k_w=2$. These
>   approximations significantly reduce the complexity of the
>   calculations (and computations) required.
>
> Reference:
>   D. R. Pauluzzi and N. C. Beaulieu, "A comparison of SNR
>   estimation techniques for the AWGN channel," IEEE
>   Trans. Communications, Vol. 48, No. 10, pp. 1681-1691, 2000.

The documentation of the constructor vaguely hints:

> `alpha`   the update rate of internal running average calculations."

I.e. probably a single-tap IIR ("exponentially weighted moving average") with feeback coefficient alpha.

Verifying that with the [source code](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-digital/lib/mpsk_snr_est.cc#L187):

```
for(int i = 0; i < noutput_items; i++) {
    double y1 = abs(input[i])*abs(input[i]);
    d_y1 = d_alpha*y1 + d_beta*d_y1;

    double y2 = abs(input[i])*abs(input[i])*abs(input[i])*abs(input[i]);
    d_y2 = d_alpha*y2 + d_beta*d_y2;
}
```

Yes, that alpha is just the coefficient of a single-tap IIR (further up you'll find `d_beta = 1 - d_alpha`).

So, this estimator should do exactly what it promises: for a zero-mean signal (where the variance is simply $\text{Var }X = \text E(X^2)$), it calculates the second and fourth central moment and then just

```
double
mpsk_snr_est_m2m4::snr()
{
  double y1_2 = d_y1*d_y1;
  d_signal = sqrt(2*y1_2 - d_y2);
  d_noise = d_y1 - sqrt(2*y1_2 - d_y2);
  return 10.0*log10(d_signal / d_noise);
}
```

So, it does the usual kurtosis-based estimate.

By the way, I'd fully agree the parameter documentation – to put it friendly – leaves a bit of room for improvement. Hit us / me up if you'd be willing to contribute a bit of a documentation improvement!

Comment: Alright, that sheds some light on the mysterious parameter `alpha`, but what about the estimators themselves? 
Why are there such discrepancies between the example on github and the same estimators in GRC? Do you recommend a specific way of calculating SNR in such a signal? Any straw to grasp on is helpful.

Comment: the cited paper is probably a pretty good straw :)

Comment: also, don't know what you mean with "discrepancies between example and GRC": That is the *exact* code used in the block. So, unless you're malforming the data you feed in there, there should be no difference.

Comment: I'll look into the paper, thanks!

As for the discrepancies - all I'm doing in GRC is file source -> throttle -> MPSK SNR Probe estimator -> SNR output connected to Message debug. I get a whole lot of -nan and numbers oscillating 0. All the parameters are default.

I've tried it without the throttle, no difference.

Comment: Hi! there's been a downvote, which is very fine, democratically and scientifically, but I don't think I made a mistake while citing the original sources and explaining what this estimator does. Would love to hear how to improve this answer!

Comment: To ease your mind - I didn't give you the downvote. I'll accept the answer as it did help a lot, but since I'm not with the company from that time, I don't think I'll ever really 'get' the answer.